# Getting Input Value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why am I getting only the first input value on all the buttons? Thank you very much!

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ErrorLog)</td>
            <td>@(item.IsPrinted == false? "Not Printed": "Printed")</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateFailed)</td>
            <input type="text" class="ord" value="@item.OrderNumber">
            <td><button class="btnRtg">Retrigger (@item.OrderNumber)</button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

JavaScript/Jquery

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){



            $('.btnRtg').on("click", function () {
                var orderNumberInput = $('.ord').val();
                alert(orderNumberInput);
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

I tried changing the names and the structure but it didnt work.

Comment: because `$('.ord').val()` returns the value of the first such input - it doesn't "know what you really mean" it does what you say

Comment: `var orderNumberInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ord').val();` could work, assuming you get the HTML correct (your input should be inside a `td`)

Comment: This seems highly sketchy. Querying inputs by CSS class name, especially given that you're generating multiple sets of inputs in your templating is not the way to go. You should probably wrap each group of inputs in a containing element. Then you can use your selectors to navigate down from that element to find the appropriate child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jaromanda X in the comment for:

1. You should wrap the `<input>` element in a `<td>` element.
2. Working with [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and `.find()` to get the input element with the `.ord` class that fall in the closest `<tr>` element.

You may also work with [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```js
var orderNumberInput = $(this).parents('tr').find('.ord').val();
```

---

Another approach is you can pass the order number value with `data` attribute in the `<button>` element.

```
<button class="btnRtg" data-order-no="@item.OrderNumber">Retrigger (@item.OrderNumber)</button>
```

And with the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get the value.

```js
var orderNumberInput = $(this).data('order-no');
```

With this approach, you don't need to create the `<input>` element just to assign and get value from it.

Comment: [Sample JS Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5nxyuy?file=index.html)